# Applescript replace characters without adding new line

Tags: applescript, command-line, automator

We have a subtitle team working for several streaming platforms and some of them use old systems that will not accept a few characters like …, “, ”, etc. So I built a script for replacing those characters and inform some that might need further attention. Problem is, the code is placing a new line at every occurrence and I can't find the reason. I don't know how to shell script, but if it is easier I will accept any suggestion.

Code:

```
on run
    set theFlags to "Characters " -- prepares te variable to store weird characters
    tell application "TextEdit" to activate
    delay 0.1
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 0 using command down -- command + A (select all)
        delay 0.1
        key code 8 using command down -- command + C (copy to clipboard)
        delay 0.2
        set theText to the clipboard
        delay 0.5
        -- REPLACE KNOWN CHARACTERS
        set theText to my replace_chars(theText, "​", "") --(0x200b) zero width space​
        delay 0.5
        set theText to my replace_chars(theText, "…", "...")
        delay 0.5
        set theText to my replace_chars(theText, "“", "\"")
        delay 0.5
        set theText to my replace_chars(theText, "”", "\"")
        delay 0.5
        set theText to my replace_chars(theText, "’", "'")
        delay 0.5
        set theText to my replace_chars(theText, "‘", "'")
        delay 0.5
        -- FLAGS STRANGE CHARACTERS
        if (theText contains "ª") then
            set theFlags to theFlags & "ª "
        end if
        if (theText contains "º") then
            set theFlags to theFlags & "º "
        end if
        if (theText contains "ᵒ") then
            set theFlags to theFlags & "ᵒ "
        end if
        if (theText contains "¨") then
            set theFlags to theFlags & "¨ "
        end if
        -- REPORT DETECTED STRANGE CHARACTERS
        if (theFlags is not "Characters ") then
            display dialog theFlags & " detected." & return & "Inform localization team to correct."
        end if
        delay 0.1
        set the clipboard to theText
        delay 0.5
    end tell
    tell application "TextEdit" to activate
    delay 0.2
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 9 using command down -- command + V (replace old text)
    end tell
end run
on replace_chars(this_text, search_string, replacement_string)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the search_string
    set the item_list to every text item of this_text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the replacement_string
    set this_text to the item_list as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return this_text
end replace_chars
```

Inicial state:

[image]

Final state:

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a sample text that this script it to act upon. Also, exactly how are you running the _code_? If in **Automator**, then please include the _workflow_ info, what _actions_ and type of _workflow_ and its settings. What version of **macOS** are you running?

Comment: Some observations about the _code_ in your question... 1. The calls to the `replace_chars(this_text, search_string, replacement_string)` _handler_ and `the clipboard` do not belong within the `tell` _block_ of **System Events**. -- 2. Since you are using **TextEdit**, there is no need to first copy the contents of the _document_ to **the clipboard** as you can simply do e.g. `tell application "TextEdit" to set theText to the text of document 1` and then just act on `theText` and when done with the _handlers_... `tell application "TextEdit" to set the text of document 1 to theText`.

Comment: 3. Anyway, I cannot reproduce the issue it work fine on my end, however, using the **the clipboard** does replace all of the **LF** (`0A`) with **CR** (`0D`) and this I'd imagine one would not want. This does not happen when not using **the clipboard**, as in 2 above. -- I would in **Terminal** run `file '/path/to/filename.txt'` on an unmodified _file_ and a modified _file_ and see what it outputs and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with:

[image]

Using the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "TextEdit"
    tell front document
        set theText to its text
        set theTextProperties to ¬
            the properties of its text
    end tell
end tell

set theText to my replaceChars(theText, "​", "")
set theText to my replaceChars(theText, "…", "...")
set theText to my replaceChars(theText, "“", "\"")
set theText to my replaceChars(theText, "”", "\"")
set theText to my replaceChars(theText, "’", "'")
set theText to my replaceChars(theText, "‘", "'")

tell application "TextEdit"
    activate
    tell front document to ¬
        set its text to theText
end tell

delay 0.1

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    key code 0 using command down

tell application "TextEdit"
    tell front document
        set its font to font of theTextProperties
        set its size to size of theTextProperties
        set its color to color of theTextProperties
    end tell
end tell

delay 0.1

tell application "System Events" to key code 125

set theFlags to "Characters "
if theText contains "ª" then
    set theFlags to theFlags & "ª "
end if
if theText contains "º" then
    set theFlags to theFlags & "º "
end if
if theText contains "ᵒ" then
    set theFlags to theFlags & "ᵒ "
end if
if theText contains "¨" then
    set theFlags to theFlags & "¨ "
end if
if theFlags is not "Characters " then
    activate
    display alert theFlags & " detected." & ¬
        linefeed & linefeed & ¬
        "Inform localization team to correct."
end if

on replaceChars(thisText, searchString, replacementString)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the searchString
    set the itemList to text items of thisText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the replacementString
    set thisText to the itemList as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return thisText
end replaceChars
```

Result:

[image]

---

**Notes:**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown above, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

- Recoded to avoid using **the clipboard**.
- Restructured code to remove improperly nested statements.
- Removed unnecessary parentheses.
- Removed unnecessary `delay` *commands*.
- Converted mismatched naming style of *variables* to **camelCase**.
- Move test for and notification of "strange characters" to the end of the process.
- Changed `display dialog` to `display alert`.
- Reworked the message use with `display alert`. Displays as, e.g.,:

[image]

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Excellent job. Working neatly with the sample file. I will adjust delays in case the subtitles are too long for processing. Thanks.

Comment: @Mateus Ribeiro, JSYK I also tested on a file with 2000 lines of text and 4 replacements per line with the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ as is and had no issues.